# Как правильно выключить кэш запросов MySQL?

Tags: mysql, кэширование

Я пытаюсь выключить кэш запросов, выполнив в SQLyog'e следующую команду:

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_type=OFF;
```

После этого запрос `SELECT @@query_cache_type;` выдаёт результат "ON".
Я рестартую сервис MySQL, снова выполняю запрос `SELECT @@query_cache_type;`, и снова получаю результат "ON". Что я делаю неправильно и как включить кэш запросов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте установить значение директивы `query_cache_type` на момент старта сервера - тогда состояние будет сохраняться и после перезагрузки. Для этого нужно найти конфигурационный файл my.cnf (в Windows my.ini) и поместить в секцию [mysqld] директиву

```
query_cache_type=0
```

После чего перезагрузить сервер.